# Syntax Error: Token 'for' is an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I'm kinda new to AngularJS, and i'm reading documentations to build a select input using the `ng-options` directive

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

my code:

```js
$scope.searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'dist1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'dist2'
    }];
```

```html
<select ng-model="searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode"
    ng-options="item as item.label for item in searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode| translate | uppercase for item in distributionCode"
    class="form-control" id="distributionCode">
    <option value="">{{'SELECT_A_VALUE' | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

But when I launch the app the following error rise up:

> "angular.js:12783 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'for' is
>   an unexpected token "

where do I get wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `translate` filter in your `ng-options`, it is total mess in your `ng-options`

Comment: You should apply translate on `item.label` like `item.label | translate` and removed it from `searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode`

Comment: You have two for loops there in ng-options. Get rid of the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Solutions
 1. Do not mix translate filter with ng-options. try using it seperately
 2. uppercase filter should not be on direct ng-option

Try using This

```
ng-options="item as (item.label | upper) for item in searchFilterDispatcher.distributionCode"
```

Thanks

Comment: your answer is the correct one, but now when i select one of the option, it is not showed in the select panel and i'm no more able to choose other options, is this an error on my script?